# Python - Read .b4u files - error sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, export

I'm trying to use http://grantcox.com.au/2012/01/decoding-b4u-binary-file-format/ Python code to export .b4u files to HTML format, but for some reason after at the program point:

```
# find the initial caret position - this changes between files for some reason - search for the "Cards" string
for i in range(3):
    addr = 104 + i*4
    if ''.join(self.parser.read('sssss', addr)) == 'Cards':
        caret = addr + 32
        break
    if caret is None:
        return
```

I get the following error:

```
if ''.join(self.parser.read('sssss', addr)) == 'Cards':
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

The Python version I'm using is: Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 20:25:12).

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: did you sovlve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working under Python 2.7.4 My Python 3.3.2 is giving me the same error. I'll get back to you if I find out how to port this piece of code to Python 3.x.x Must have something to do with unicode being default for strings in Python 3.
Here is a solution I came up with:

```
def read(self, fmt, offset):
    if self.filedata is None:
        return None
    read = struct.unpack_from('<' + fmt, self.filedata, offset)
    xread = []
    for each in range(0,len(read)):
        try:
                xread.append(read[each].decode())
        except:
                xread.append(read[each])
    read = xread
    if len(read) == 1:
        return read[0]
return read

def string(self, offset):
    if self.filedata is None:
        return None
    s = u''
    if offset > 0:
        length = self.read('H', offset)
        for i in range(length):
            raw = self.read('H', offset + i*2 +2)
            char = raw ^ 0x7E
            s = s + chr(char)
    return s

def plain_fixed_string(self, offset):
    if self.filedata is None:
        return None
    plain_bytes = struct.unpack_from('<ssssssssssssssssssssssss', self.filedata, offset)
    xplain_bytes = []
    for each in range(0,len(plain_bytes)):
            try:
                    xplain_bytes.append(plain_bytes[each].decode())
            except:
                    xplain_bytes.append(plain_bytes[each])
    plain_bytes = xplain_bytes
    plain_string = ''.join(plain_bytes).strip('\0x0')
    return plain_string
```

You can just use these methods instead of provided by original author.
Beware that you should also change unicode() to str() and unichr() to chr() if you see it anywhere. Also remember that print is a function and cannot be used without brackets ().